# At what point of this program will we receive a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I was given the following code and asked at what point will we get a message that says that a segmentation fault has occurred.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct N {
 struct N *n;
 char *q;
 int a;
} *q;
int foo(void) {
 N *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
 p->a = 42;
 p->q = "life,␣universe,␣everything";
 p->n = (struct N *)p;
 q = p;
 free(p);
 return 1;
}

int main() {
 free( strcpy((char *)malloc(20),foo() + "Hello,␣World\n"));
 (void) printf("q=%p\n", q);
 (void) printf("q->a=%d\n", q->a);
 (void) printf("q->q=%s\n", q->q);
 return 0;
}
```

The answer is that it will happen only after the second to last line in the main part, `(void) printf("q->q=%s\n", q->q);`

Can someone please explain why it will happen at this point exactly?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A "segmentation fault" is not required to occur at all according to the C standard. And it might occur at a different line on a different OS or compiler (version)

Comment: The code you provided doesn't compile.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to seg fault as already mentioned. Nevertheless, likely the intent of the question is to ask which line causes "a problem". For that, the line before you identified `printf("q->a=%d\n", q->a);` already has a problem. At that point `q` points to freed memory so any derefence of it results in undefined behaviour. At the end of the day, whoever gave you this question has not really got the technical details correct (or at least it is unclear).

Comment: If that code compiled for you, it's probably because you compiled it as C++ rather than as C.

Comment: `N *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` invalid C code.  `N` not defined.

Answer (score 1):

A more correct way to word the question is "When does the behavior of the program become undefined", or "What is the first place that a segmentation fault could occur"

So, to answer that:

Consider this line:
`free( strcpy((char *)malloc(20),foo() + "Hello,␣World\n"));`

EDIT (remove this): *This line is non-sensical. Adding an `int` to a literal `char *` doesn't mean anything. My C compiler issues a warning and moves on, so I will too.*

EDIT (add this): As pointed out in the comments, `foo()` returns 1, so this passes `"ello,␣World\n"` to strcpy. This is ok, because this is less than the 20 chars allocated.  It's a warning in my C compiler because it's *weird*.

The question is: is this less than 20 bytes.  I think so? So, this line basically just has the side-effect of calling `foo()`

`foo` is just gibberish code -- but I will put comments in it to see if any part of it is undefined:

```
int foo(void) {
 // This is defined (added struct so it compiles)
 struct N *p = malloc(sizeof *p);

 // This is defined
 p->a = 42;

 // This is defined
 p->q = "life,␣universe,␣everything";

 // This is defined
 p->n = (struct N *)p;

 // This is defined
 q = p;

 // This is defined
 free(p);

 // Right now, q is pointing at free space -- it is very bad to derefence q
 return 1;
}
```

Going back to `main()`

`(void) printf("q=%p\n", q);`

This prints the `q` pointer value -- it is not a dereference, so it's ok.

`(void) printf("q->a=%d\n", q->a);`

I say that this is undefined.  You are clearly dereferencing `q` which is pointing at free space.  `q->a` is an int sized location in free space and you are reading it.  Now, if the memory has not been reclaimed, this *might* not segfault. It is still not correct or defined.

Now we get to the line that you are told will segfault:

`(void) printf("q->q=%s\n", q->q);`

This is undefined for the same reason that `q->a` is.

When I run it I get

```
q=0x7fc30f4017c0
q->a=2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So, you see: it did not print 42 for q->a and it didn't get to the next line.  The program became undefined and did one of the things it's allowed to do, which is anything it wants. For example

1. It can print the wrong number
2. It can segfault
3. It can work perfectly
4. It can be a vector for a security exploit that takes over your machine and gives a hacker access to your bank accounts.

This explains it better: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110929-00/?p=9523

More: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: "Adding an int to a literal char * doesn't mean anything. My C compiler issues a warning ". There is nothing wrong with adding an _int_ and char*. Assuming _p_ is a pointer and _i_ is an integer, (i + p) means &p[i], provided p[i] exists. I wonder why your compiler issues a warning. For example, (2 + "Hello") is a char* pointing to the string "llo"

Comment: `// This is defined N *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` invalid C code.  `N` not defined.    Perhaps you are compiling as C++?

Comment: `(void) printf("q=%p\n", q);` is UB as `q` is not a valid pointer given the `free(p);` of `foo()`, not "so it's ok.".

Comment: @LxerLx is correct, adding the int does mean something -- since foo() always returns 1, it passes "ello,␣World\n" to strcpy -- the important thing is that that is less than 20 chars.  @chux -- I added the `struct` in my C file, but I left it as the OP posted.  Also, I am pretty sure that printing `q` is ok, as that is not a dereference.

Comment: @LouFranco "I am pretty sure that printing q is ok, as that is not a dereference." Hmm, based on experience or spec?  So you are suggesting printing an invalid pointer is OK?

Answer (score 1):

To complement the excelent response of @Lou Franco, I think the answer that whoever asked the question was expecting is:

```
p->q = "life,␣universe,␣everything";
```

You are assigning a `string` (in C a `const char*`) to a pointer inside a structure who's memory has not been allocated properly, that is just a pointer to char, if you  do `(void) printf("q=%lu\n", sizeof(q->q));` you will get 8 in most cases (depending on the system) witch is the size (number of bytes assigned) to a pointer to `char`, well `q->q` needs more bytes, 13 seems to be the smaller size permitted for my tests, hence the segmentation fault when you try to print it.

Here is a sample of [CODE](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/SlightThankfulZip) with some changes that runs:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct N {
    struct N *n;
    char q[20];
    int a;
} *q;

int foo(void) {
    struct N *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    p->a = 42;
    strcpy(p->q, "life,␣universe,␣everything");
    p->n = (struct N*)p;
    q = p;
    free(p);
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    free( strcpy((char*)malloc(20),foo() + "Hello,␣World\n"));

    (void) printf("q=%lu\n", sizeof(q->q));  //size of the string

    (void) printf("q=%p\n", q);
    (void) printf("q->a=%d\n", q->a);
    (void) printf("q->q=%s\n", q->q);
    return 0;
}
```

Since you freed `p` and by consequence `q`, nothing is printed or in some cases some gibberish or even the string itself depending on the compiler, but if remove `free(p)` then the string is printed always.